# Solve a System with Variable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given these matrices, how does one find two *real* solutions?

$dx/dt$ = 
$\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -5\\ 
5 & 3 
\end{bmatrix}x$

with $x(0) = \begin{bmatrix}
2\\ 
-3 
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Have you learned eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes. I can solve for them, but am mainly unsure about two things: the "x" in the first equation––does that simply mean a matrix containing (x, y)? And the x(0): where do I plug in these values?

Comment: Yes, x is vector. So, you are solving a 2x2 system and will get two solution and the IV is one for each equation. In matrix form, we have $x' = Ax$ with an IC $x(0)$.

Comment: Thanks! So, are 2 and -3 the constants?

Comment: Yes, correct, when you find $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$, you will make $t=0$ and set the result equal to its respective IC $(2 ~\text{or}~ -3)$ to solve for the constants and get an exact solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

We are given the system:

$$x' = Ax = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & -5\\ 
5 & 3 
\end{bmatrix}x$$

with IC:

$$x(0) = \begin{bmatrix} 2\\ -3 \end{bmatrix}$$

The general solution will be:

$$x_1(t) = c_2 \sin 4 t + c_1 (3 \sin 4 t + 4 \cos 4 t)$$

$$x_2(t) =  c_1 \sin 4 t + c_2 (4 \cos 4 t - 3 \sin 4 t)$$

Using the IC, will yield the final solution of:

$$x_1(t) = \frac{21}{4} \sin 4 t + 2 \cos 4 t$$

$$x_2(t) = \frac{19}{4} \sin 4 t - 3 \cos 4 t$$

Comment: Nice work! Why no $\color{red}{\bf \uparrow}$ until now? who knows ???

Comment: Yes...and more users available to answer...fewer questions...it does seem, at times, to get awfully competitive, which is not my style. Maybe I'll devote more time to the archive of *Unanswered Questions* ;-)

Comment: +1 ${\uparrow}{\large{\uparrow}}{\Large{\uparrow}}{\LARGE{\uparrow}}{}{}{}$